# Print from MySQL to PHP issue

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm echoing a large paragraph or text in PHP there's always a big space on the first line.

[image: Spacing Problem]

Is there a way to fix that? I don't have a space or anything and when I check in the database everything is fine.

```
<pre>
            <?php if ($rows['section'] == "text"){
                echo ($rows['code']);
            }else{ ?>
        <code class="<?php echo($rows['section']); ?>" id="copyCode">
            <?php echo $rows['code'] ?>
        </code>
        <?php } ?>
    </pre>
```

Comment: How are you outputting it? Is there any CSS styling in play?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, your data in MySQL, etc.

Comment: we dont have **software to convert your image into code**... so pls post some code...

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your code is?

Comment: This is the website: https://www.jmdev.ca/sheridan/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
<code class="<?php echo($rows['section']); ?>" id="copyCode">
    <?php echo $rows['code'] ?>
</code>
```

with

```
<code class="<?php echo($rows['section']); ?>" id="copyCode"><?php echo $rows['code'] ?></code>
```

from what i can see on the website, there is a breakline and spacing before the code is outputted

https://www.dropbox.com/s/78lspdqpopsqb2g/Screenshot%202014-10-17%2000.57.08.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks that was the problem!